# Problems with input on new version of matlab. Trying to use old program

Tags: matlab, input

Edit: I now have the first part of the program working by entering the equation with ' ' on either side of the equation (thanks for the help). Now I seem to be having a related problem farther down the program with a chunk that looks like this:

```
for J = 1:M
    Z = H*F(J,M,V,ss);
    K1(J) = Z;
end;
```

It's giving me this error:

```
??? Undefined function or method 'F' for input arguments of type
'cell'.

Error in ==> RungeKuttaSystem at 110
   Z = H*F(J,M,V,ss);
```

Again it seems like it doesn't like the format of my equation, and I don't quite understand what the 'cell' is doing. Please be patient, again I'm doing my best to figure this out on my own, but I'm stuck. Thanks

From original question:
I am working on a project for a college numerical methods class, and my textbook (Burden and Faires 9e) has an outdated online companion that includes matlab code for some of the algorithms we're working with. The programs were posted in 2004, so obviously they were written for an earlier version of matlab, but I have run ten or fifteen of them and they have all worked fine with MatLab 2010b. This particular program seems to be incompatible with the new version.

The beginning of the code:

```
% RUNGE-KUTTA FOR SYSTEMS OF DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS ALGORITHM 5.7
%
% TO APPROXIMATE THE SOLUTION OF THE MTH-ORDER SYSTEM OF FIRST-
% ORDER INITIAL-VALUE PROBLEMS
%            UJ' = FJ( T, U1, U2, ..., UM ), J = 1, 2, ..., M
%            A <= T <= B, UJ(A) = ALPHAJ, J = 1, 2, ..., M
% AT (N+1) EQUALLY SPACED NUMBERS IN THE INTERVAL (A,B).
%
% INPUT:   ENDPOINTS A,B; NUMBER OF EQUATIONS M; INITIAL
%          CONDITIONS ALPHA1, ..., ALPHAM; INTEGER N.
%
% OUTPUT:  APPROXIMATION WJ TO UJ(T) AT THE (N+1) VALUES OF T.
 syms('OK', 'M', 'I', 'A', 'B', 'ALPHA', 'N', 'FLAG');
 syms('NAME', 'OUP', 'H', 'T', 'J', 'W', 'L', 'K','ss');
 syms('K1','K2','K3','K4','Z','kk');
 TRUE = 1;
 FALSE = 0;
 fprintf(1,'This is the Runge-Kutta Method for Systems of m equations\n');
 fprintf(1,'This program uses the file F.m.  If the number of equations\n');
 fprintf(1,'exceeds 7, then F.m must be changed.\n');
 OK = FALSE;
 while OK == FALSE
     fprintf(1,'Input the number of equations\n');
     M = input(' ');
     if M <= 0 | M > 7
          fprintf(1,'Number must be a positive integer < 8\n');
     else 
           OK = TRUE;
     end;
  end;
  ss = cell(M,1);
 for I = 1:M
     fprintf(1,'Input the function F_(%d) in terms of t and y1 ... y%d\n', I,M);
     fprintf(1,'For example: y1-t^2+1 \n');
     kk = input(' ');
     ss{I} = kk;
  end;
```

Comment: It's not possible to answer the question, because we don't know which datatype is expected for `ss`. `kk = input(' ','s');` would remove this error, but might cause other errors. `ss` seems to be either function handles or string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet reproduces the issue:

```
clear 
input('')
```

Then in the command window simply type:

```
a

Error using input
Undefined function or variable 'a'.
```

This is because you need to type:

```
'a'
```

i.e. you need to supply a string not the value within `a` (unless it contains a string).

Comment: Thank you very much, this seemed to work. I am having a related problem lower down in the code related to using the equation in a function. It would be really helpful if you could take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: @user3087978 There are tons of your same question on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your function `F` is not in scope.

This type of error is typically not caused by feeding the wrong input to `F` so that would not be the first thing to look at.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dennis. I actually realized that I was missing the .m file for the F function. I have rectified this and everything works fine now.